# Using magit style diffing generally

Tags: emacs, magit

I enjoy using magit and whenever I have to look at a diff outside of magit, it
occurs to me how inferior the default diff experience is.

Two aspects in particular:

1) refine diff automatically as I move into new hunks.
    - `diff-auto-refine-mode` is not a substitute because I don't always move
      with M-p and M-n.

2) white space differences are really obvious because
   `magit-whitespace-warning-face` face is applied.

Is there a way to get these two features in `diff-mode`

Answer (score 1):

I think sending a message to the Magit maintainers asking them to submit those changes for inclusion in diff-mode might do it.